# Listview not scroll up when keybord appear

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adjustpan

I have made custom list view with edit text and every listview item have a edit text, when I click on edit text of listview item then list view not scroll up , whole activity is scroll up

I used  `adjustResize` in my manifest but did not work

```
<activity android:name=".CreateChallan" android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"

             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Please suggest me how i can fix this issue

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you tried to scroll list view to your item in case of keyboard open?

Comment: @sandrstar Still not wrking